# Which Schema.org type to use for computer games?

Tags: seo, e-commerce, product, schema.org

The Schema.org website offers a variety of types for books, movies, recipes etc., but there doesn't appear to be a specific one for computer games.

This leaves me with two options:

- `CreativeWork`: http://schema.org/CreativeWork
- `Product`: http://schema.org/Product

Bearing in mind that the website I am working on is an e-commerce site for games, I'm inclined to go with the `Product` option.

Unless anyone has alternate suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 11 December 2014 there is a new type available:

http://schema.org/VideoGame

This is both a subtype of a new CreativeWork type, [Game](http://schema.org/Game), and of SoftwareApplication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [Software Application](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) is the thing you’re looking for. Under **Properties from SoftwareApplication** the first property is **applicationCategory**. The description says:

> Type of software application, e.g. "**Game**, Multimedia".

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've just come across an extension to the product schema which defines PC Games.

http://www.productontology.org/doc/PC_game#microdata

So it looks like Product is the right option to go with, even if you don't extend it.

Hopefully this will come in handy for other developers working on e-commerce games websites like myself.